# having issue with array in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I am creating an e-commerce web in laravel 5.8.
I am having an error in splitting a multidimensional array.

```
@php
    $ProductAttributeToCategory=App\Models\Products\ProductAttributeToCategory::whereCategory_id($Product->category_id)->first();
    $categoryTag= json_decode($ProductAttributeToCategory->choice_options);
    $tags=json_decode($Product->variation_option);
                                                                        
@endphp
@foreach ($categoryTag as $r=>$item)
    <div class="row mt-2">
        <div class="col-2 mr-0 pr-0 pl-1 text-right">
            <label for="{{ $item->title }}">{{ $item->title }}</label>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="choice_no[]" value="{{ $r }}" >
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="choice[]" value="{{ $item->title }}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-9 mr-0  ml-2">
            <select class="form-control select2-multiple tags" style="width:100%" id="{{ $item->title }}" name="choice_options_{{ $r }}[]" data-toggle="select2" multiple="multiple" onchange="update_sku()"  data-placeholder="Choose {{ $item->title }} ...">
                    @foreach ($item->options as $option)
                        <option value="{{ $option }}" >{{ $option }}</option>
                    @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

I want to select elements from `$categoryTag` variable that is available in `$tags`
here is the structure of both variables.

```
$categoryTag
```

[image]

```
$tags
```

[image]

please give me some solution to this problem.

Comment: do you want the key at which each $categoryTag->options has the same value as for each $tag->options. specify in detail what do you want and why so we can understand the scenario.

Comment: Inside your `@foreach ($item->options as $option)`, can't you just use a Blade `@if` condition to check if categoryTag is in Tag?

Comment: `'I want to select elements from $categoryTag variable that is available in $tags`' which **elements** are you referring to?